# How to calculate cryptocurrency pair to usd

Tags: exchange-rate

I understand how to calculate pair like BTC/GBP or ETH/JPY to usd.
But i cant understand how to calculate pairs like XMR/LTC or LTC/BNB.
Help me please with calculate it
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I think I read somewhere earlier that conversions like this are often done across BTC (can't find the link now..). I will be interested in the answers as well!